# Net::Telnet::Cisco not able to parse a prompt in Cisco Switch in perl

Tags: perl, switch-statement, telnet, router, cisco

I'm trying to automate a switch using perl and I'm not able to parse a prompt for a particular command. Im using print and waitfor method.

The prompt is basically a confirmation message, where I need to hit enter or press y. 
Here is the prompt

```
Clear "show interface" counters on this interface [confirm]
```

And this is the error Im getting

```
Can't parse prompt: '/Clear "show interface" counters on this interface [confirm]/' at access_endis.pl line 27
```

Please help. 
I edited the prompt to above and Im getting a error like  Timed out matching the prompt.

Comment: Did you use the default prompt match or some specific one ? It would be nice as well to have what you really tried (code snipet).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following statement and it worked for me, although it doesn't match the prompt.

> $session->waitfor_pause(1);

will actually overrides the `cmd` prompt matching and instead waits for 1 second.